# Endless scrolling not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I'm following along with Ryan Bates' http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised. The initial alert box, he demonstrates, that appears after scrolling to the bottom works fine, but I'm unable to get anything after that to work properly.

Let's have a look:

photos/index.html.haml

```
  #photos
    = render @photos
  = will_paginate @photos
```

photos_controller.rb

```
def index
  @photos = Photo.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page])
```

photos.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $(window).scroll ->
if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
  $.getScript($('.pagination .next_page').attr('href'))
```

photos/index.js.erb

```
$('#photos').append('<%= j render(@photos) %>');
<% if @photos.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@photos) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

As far as I can tell, I've set up everything properly, but when I scroll to the bottom of the page, nothing get loaded. I've just noticed it DOES make a GET request in my logs, but nothing actually appears in the browser... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, finally figured this out. I had a `respond_to` block in my index action and needed to add a `format.js` to that block. Works perfectly now.